# How can I delete drawn rectangles in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, destroy

I want to randomly draw rectangles on the screen, however if the number of the rects that have already been drawn surpasses lets say 3, then I want to start deleting the "older ones", meaning those that are being drawn on the screen for the most time.

```
import pygame
import random
import time
pygame.init()

x_axis = [500, 650, 350, 400]
y_axis = [100, 50, 450, 300]
sq_width = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
sec = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
sq_display = []

class Squares:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = width

    def draw(self):
        a = pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (random.choice(x_axis), random.choice(y_axis), self.width, self.height))
        sq_display.append(a)
        if len(sq_display) > 3:
            sq_display.remove(sq_display[0])
        time.sleep(random.choice(sec))
        return
```

I tried storing the rectangle into a variable each time and appending it to a list, thinking that later on I would be able to remove it. Well, it did not work. So I would like to know if there is any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the generation of new squares from the `draw` method:

```py
class Squares:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = width

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
```

You have to redraw the entire scene in each frame of the application loop. Clear the display before drawing the squares, then draw all squares in the list and finally update the display:

```py
while run:
    # [...]  

    a = Squares(random.choice(x_axis), random.choice(y_axis), 
                random.choice(sq_width), random.choice(sq_width))
    sq_display.append(a)
    if len(sq_display) > 3:
        sq_display.remove(sq_display[0])

    window.fill(0)
    for r in sq_display:
        r.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

If you want to keep the application responding, then you can't delay the application loop by `time.sleep`. Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get the current number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` and create a new square when a random time has elaped:

```py
next_square_time = 0
while run:
    # [...]

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if next_square_time <= current_time:
        next_square_time += random.choice(sec) * 1000 

        # create new square
        # [...]
```

---

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

x_axis = [500, 650, 350, 400]
y_axis = [100, 50, 450, 300]
sq_width = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
sec = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
sq_display = []

class Squares:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = width

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

next_square_time = 0
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if next_square_time <= current_time:
        next_square_time += random.choice(sec) * 1000    
        a = Squares(random.choice(x_axis), random.choice(y_axis), random.choice(sq_width))
        sq_display.append(a)
        if len(sq_display) > 3:
            sq_display.remove(sq_display[0])

    window.fill(0)
    for r in sq_display:
        r.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I was also having trouble with the runtime because it didn't run smoothly and I wondered why. So you basically helped me with two of my difficulties. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, why are you multiplying by 1000?

Comment: @GeorgeAvrabos 1 second == 1000 milliseconds. `pygame.time.get_ticks()` returns the number of milliseconds (as mentioned in the answer)

Comment: Ah ok i didn't see milliseconds sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Store a queue of all currently drawn rectangles and whenever the list exceeds length say 3, simply draw a white rectangle (or whatever color your background is) using the stored coordinates.

Comment: Yeah but won't that overload it? Because then I'll have hundreds of rectangles on my screen.